# canDisplayBannerAds and Airplane Mode

Tags: ios, ios7, adbannerview, airplane-mode

I'm testing my app in the Sandbox, and I'm using canDisplayBannerAds with iOS7. I had this working acceptably until I did some tests where I started the app in Airplane Mode (important to me because I need to detect if there is a network connection and if the user has paid to remove ads). With the iPad in Airplane Mode, I launch the app. Of course, no ads are displayed. Then, I switch to Settings (I don't explicitly quit the app), turn Airplane Mode off (the network is available again), but ads don't come back. Even if I set canDisplayBannerAds to YES again, it doesn't appear to help. The network is available, canDisplayBannerAds is YES, but no ads appear. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Ads won't appear in a number of circumstances, and I'm guessing this is one of them.

The real question you need to ask is

1.) How many users are going to find this out?

and

2.) Who has the time or effort to do this Airplane-mode-toggle-dance for *your* app. Apps are ephemeral experiences for the most part.

Comment: And 3) Code will have bugs (even if seemingly caused by Apple). Live with it? ;).

Comment: @ChrisPrince if the time it takes to fix an issue costs more than the value of the fix, then yes. Building products is the task of choosing which work has more value than other work.